# How to get video height in jquery

Tags: jquery, video

With this code `_height` always zero. Please help.

```
var path = "http://localhost:49634/Uploads/TimeLineImages/05_24_2018_12_48_32_Entering_manufacturing.jpg";
var video = $('<video />', {
  id: 'videoddd',
  src: path,
  type: 'video/mp4'
});
var _height = video[0].videoHeight;
alert(_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
video.setAttribute('height', '300');
video.setAttribute('width ', '700');
or setting its width and height properties

var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
video.height = 300;
video.width = 700;
```

Comment: I want height of the video using its path

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that the `src` you're setting for this video is a JPG image. I presume that's just a typo.

With regards to the problem, for the dimensions of an element to be calculated it must exist within the DOM. You cannot get the dimensions of an element in memory. Therefore you need to first `append()` the video. You will also need to wait for the browser to load the metadata for the video, which you can achieve using an event handler, like this:

```
var video = $('<video />', {
  id: 'videoddd',
  src: path,
  type: 'video/mp4'
}).appendTo('#your-container');

$('#your-container').on('loadedmetadata', 'video', function() {
  var _height = this.videoHeight;
  console.log(_height);
});
```

If you don't want the video to be displayed at that point, you could use CSS to set it (or its parent element) to `display: none`.

Comment: I need _height as global variable.

Comment: var path = window.location.origin + data.TimeLineMediaList[i].TimeLineMediaPath;
                   var video = $('<video />', {
                       id: 'video',
                       src: path,
                       type: 'video/mp4'
                   }).appendTo('#DecadeYearsDiv');



                   $('#DecadeYearsDiv').on('loadedmetadata', 'video', function () {
                       _height = this.videoHeight;
                
                   });

                   alert(_height);

Comment: So define `var _height` outside of the event handler. Note that it will be `undefined` until the `loadedmetadata` event has fired though. 'd also suggest you avoid global vars though, as they are bad practice.

Comment: _height value is using some other place.So it should be global. @Rory

Comment: Don't use globals. Aside from the fact that they won't work here due to the async nature of the way the dimensions of the video are retrieved (in other words, you need to wait for the video to be loaded before you can figure out how big it is). You need to change your logic to work as I outlined in my question. If you need to use `_height` in another place, pass it to a function as an argument.